# Problems when extracting PHP repeated code block into a function

Tags: php

I have a PHP script which is to process user login. In this script there are 3 tables to query and check when a person logs in(to check if this person is a User, an Employer or an Admin). I simply used if() else () to continuously query the 3 table. It works, but there are many repeated code.

Now I want to extract those repeated code block and put them into a function, but since the original 3 table queries are nested in if...else..., how to pull the code block into a function? Is this something called recursive function?

Here is the script:

```
<?php # Script  - login.php

// This is the login page for the site.


require ('includes/config.inc.php');
$page_title = 'Login';
include (HEADER);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        require (MYSQL);

        // Login Validation: email + password  
        // Trim all the incoming data:
        $trimmed = array_map('trim', $_POST);

        // Validate the email address:
        if (filter_var($trimmed['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $trimmed['email']);
        } else {
                $e = FALSE;
                echo '<p class="error">You forgot to enter your email address!</p>';
        }

        // Validate the password:
        if (preg_match('/^\w{4,20}$/', $trimmed['pass'])) {  //Here the password input name is pass in the form below!!
                $p = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $trimmed['pass']);
        } else {
                $p = FALSE;
                echo '<p class="error">You forgot to enter your password!</p>';
        }

        if ($e && $p) { // If email and password are validated.

                // First query the users table:
                $q = "SELECT user_id, first_name, DATE_FORMAT(last_login_time, '%a, %b %e at %l:%i%p') as f_last_login_time, last_login_time FROM users WHERE (email='$e' AND pass=SHA1('$p')) AND active IS NULL";

                $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

                if (@mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) { // A match was made in the user table

                        // Register the values:
                        $_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);


                        // Update last_login_time column when a User logs in                                  
                        $q = "UPDATE users SET last_login_time=NOW()";

                        $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br>MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

                        $test_affected_rows = mysqli_affected_rows($dbc); // get around debug issue

                        if ($test_affected_rows != 1) {  

                                echo '<p class="error">There is some system error, please contact administrator!</p>';

                        }

                        mysqli_free_result($r);  
                        mysqli_close($dbc);   

                        // Redirect the user to loggedin_user.php page:
                        $url = BASE_URL . 'loggedin_user.php'; // Define the URL.
                        ob_end_clean(); // Delete the buffer.
                        header("Location: $url");
                        exit(); // Quit the script.

                        } else { // Continue querying the employers table.
                                $q = "SELECT employer_id, first_name, DATE_FORMAT(last_login_time, '%a, %b %e at %l:%i%p') as f_last_login_time, last_login_time FROM employers WHERE (email='$e' AND pass=SHA1('$p')) AND active IS NULL";

                                $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

                                if (@mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) { // A match was made in the employers table

                                // Register the values:
                                $_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);



                                // Update last_login_time column when an Employer logs in                                  
                                $q = "UPDATE employers SET last_login_time=NOW()";

                                $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br>MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

                                $test_affected_rows = mysqli_affected_rows($dbc); // get around debug issue

                                if ($test_affected_rows != 1) {  

                                        echo '<p class="error">There is some system error, please contact administrator!</p>';

                                }

                                mysqli_free_result($r);   
                                mysqli_close($dbc);   

                                // Redirect the user to loggedin_employer.php page:
                                $url = BASE_URL . 'loggedin_employer.php'; // Define the URL.
                                ob_end_clean(); // Delete the buffer.
                                header("Location: $url");
                                exit(); // Quit the script.

                        } else { // Continue querying the administrators table.
                                // Administrators table doesn't contain the Active field, as no registration process needed.
                                $q = "SELECT admin_id, first_name, DATE_FORMAT(last_login_time, '%a, %b %e at %l:%i%p') as f_last_login_time, last_login_time FROM administrators WHERE (email='$e' AND pass=SHA1('$p'))";

                                $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

                                if (@mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) { // A match was made in the administrator table

                                // Register the values:
                                $_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

                                // Update last_login_time column when an Administrator logs in                                  
                                $q = "UPDATE administrators SET last_login_time=NOW()";

                                $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br>MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

                                $test_affected_rows = mysqli_affected_rows($dbc); // get around debug issue

                                if ($test_affected_rows != 1) {  

                                        echo '<p class="error">There is some system error, please contact administrator!</p>';

                                }

                                mysqli_free_result($r);   
                                mysqli_close($dbc);   
                                // Redirect the user:
                                // Redirect the user to loggedin_admin.php page:
                                $url = BASE_URL . 'loggedin_admin.php'; // Define the URL.
                                ob_end_clean(); // Delete the buffer.
                                header("Location: $url");
                                exit(); // Quit the script.
                        } else { // If email and password were not validated
        echo '<p class="error">The email or password you entered is not correct. Please try again.</p>';
                        }
                    }
             }

        }
        mysqli_close($dbc);  

} // End of SUBMIT conditional.
?>

<h1>Login</h1>
<p>Your browser must allow cookies in order to log in.</p>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>          
                <p><b>Email Address:</b> <input type="text" name="email" size="20" maxlength="60"  value="<?php if (isset($_POST['email'])) echo $_POST['email']; ?>" /></p>
                <p><b>Password:</b> <input type="password" name="pass" size="20" maxlength="20" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['pass'])) echo $_POST['pass']; ?>" /></p>
                <div align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /></div>
        </fieldset>
</form>

<?php include (FOOTER); ?>
```

I tried to make a function like this:

```
 function login_process($q_check_table, $q_update_last_login){

            // First query the users table:
            $q1 = $q_check_table;

            $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q1) or trigger_error("Query: $q1\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

            if (@mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) { // A match was made in the user table
                    // Register the values:
                    $_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);


                    // Update last_login_time column when a User logs in                                  
                    $q2 = $q_update_last_login;

                    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q2) or trigger_error("Query: $q2\n<br>MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

                    $test_affected_rows = mysqli_affected_rows($dbc); // get around debug issue

                    if ($test_affected_rows != 1) {

                            echo '<p class="error">There is some system error, please contact administrator!</p>';
                    }
            }
    }
```

But due to the nested if...else...., this seems not right.

Comment: Why are there three tables? Why not just one users table, with a role ID, and a role table with ID and associated values? The problem seems to be poor db design.

Comment: Because these 3 types of users have some different columns, and if I just use a BIG USERS table, then there will rows containing many empty columns. The database design is in my another post, you can see all the table definition here.

Comment: See the upvoted answer to your previous question - your database is full of duplicates and needs proper normalizing, so you would only perform the search on the single user table. This will not be BIG but smaller, containing just id, email and password, plus role. The remaining data is in job_seeker/job_poster/admin tables